# FormatException: Unexpected character

Tags: flutter, dart

i am facing this problem . the code is correct i guess !
[image]
and this is the Api :
[image]

Comment: take a look at the values that are being serialized into JSON in your **data** model. The image, are you encoding it as a base64-encoded string perhaps?